# Conditional covariance

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Just a simple question when we have $v_{st} = \operatorname{cov}(B_s, B_t\mid Z)$, where $B_t$ is a brownian motion. I know that the answer is $\min(s, t) - E[B_s Z]E[B_t Z]/E[Z^2]$ but i don't know how it is obtained.
 I don't know if it's ok:
 $v_{st} = E[(B_s - E[B_s\mid Z])(B_t - E[B_t\mid Z])\mid Z]$.

Comment: The answer cannot be what you write since $v_{st}$ is a random variable (measurable with respect to $Z$).

Comment: Then how about if I write $v_{st} =  E[B_s B_t|Z] - E[B_s| Z]E[B_t| Z] = E[B_s B_t|Z] - E[B_s Z]E[B_tZ]Z^2/E[Z^2]^2$, since $E[B_t |Z] = E[B_t Z]Z/E[Z^2]$, and then: $E[v_{st}]= min(s, t) - E[B_s Z] E[B_t Z]/E[Z^2]$.
 However in the article "The value of an Asian Option", by Robers and Shi we have:
 $v_{st} = min(s, t) - E[B_s Z] E[B_t Z]/E[Z^2]$ so I don't know what to say.